# Searching Local Venues With Foursquare API

Tags: php, foursquare

I am searching foursquare for venues around my area. I cannot get the search function to work.
This is the documentation on it,

I believe my problem is in the http request but I don't get why =the result is always null or how to troubleshoot it from here.

[Click Here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search)

This is my search form,

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <div class="signup-form">
                        <form class="clearfix" action="actions/fsSearch.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h3>sup bro</h3>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" placeholder="do iT">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="post" class="btn btn-huge btn-info">Search For Places!</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my search foursquare script,

```
<?php

$client_id = "foo";
$secret = "foo";
$redirect = "http://www.example.com/sandbox";
$query = $_POST['query'];

$fsSearch = file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
  ?client_id=" . $client_id . "
  &client_secret=" . $secret . "
  &v=20140623
  &ll=40.7,-74
  &query=".$query);

$searchResults = json_decode($fsSearch,true);      
      header("Location: http://www.example.com/sandbox");      

?>
```

Then when I `var_dump($searchResults);`
I get a `null` result.

I dont see what I am doing wrong here...

This is my try with `Curl`

```
<?php

$client_id = "foo";
$secret = "foo";
$redirect = "http://www.example.com/sandbox";
$query = $_POST['query'];

echo $query;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={$client_id}&client_secret={$secret}&v=20140623&ll=40.7,-74&query={$query}",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

   var_dump($response);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `curl`?

Comment: I have struggled to get this far... I have never done anything with curl.

Comment: did you get a response with curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is epically late, but i just got this to work by removing the line feeds in your API request and wanted to submit this encase anyone arrived here via google (like i did!)

Change this:

```
$fsSearch = file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
 ?client_id=" . $client_id . "
 &client_secret=" . $secret . "
 &v=20140623
 &ll=40.7,-74
 &query=".$query);
```

To this:

```
$fsSearch = file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=" . $client_id . "&client_secret=" . $secret . "&v=20140623&ll=40.7,-74&query=".$query);
```